# Mass ids request to Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get and array of more then 900 ids in this way, but I get an error message.

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . implode(',', $array);
$result = file_get_contents($url);
```

I think because the list is too big I got this error - if I shorten the list facebook gets me the JSON.

Is there any suggestion to get it in another fashion? (maybe batch call, or something like curl? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way is to implement a batch call with smaller API calls.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests